# For any monic irreducible $f\in F[x]$ with $\deg(f)|[K:F]$, there is $\alpha \in K$ such that $m_{F}(\alpha)=f$

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

I am in trouble to prove the following problem.

> Let $F$ be a finite field and $K$ be an extension of $F$ such that $[K:F]=n$. Then show that for any monic irreducible polynomial $f\in F[x]$ of degree $d$ dividing $n$, there exists $\alpha\in K$ such that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$, $m_{F}(\alpha)$, is equal to $f$.

What I have been trying is as following. Firstly, I observed that $F$ should be a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ for some prime $p$. Noting that $F$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ for some positive integer $m$, I also noted that $K\cong \mathbb{F}_{p^{mn}}$. We know $\mathbb{F_{p^{nm}}}$ is Galois over $\mathbb{F_{p^m}}$ so I conclude that $K$ is Galois over $F$.  And then I noted that $f$ should be a divisor of $x^{p^{nm}}-x$. But actually, I am not quite sure about it. I hope to have any help on this problem.

Comment: If $f$ is irreducibe then $F[x]/(f)$ is a finite field with $q=p^{m \deg(f)}$ elements so it is the splitting field of $x^q-x$ (ie. there is a unique finite field of a given cardinality) and $x^q-x$ splits completely in $K$ because $K$ is the splitting field of $x^{q^{n/\deg(f)}}-x$ whose roots contain those of $x^q-x$, thus $K$ contains a root of $f$

Comment: A finite extension of finite fields is separable.The so called theorem of the "primitive element" says that any finite separable extension  K/F is simple, i.e. there exists $\alpha\in K$ s.t. $K=F(\alpha)$. Then the minimal polynomial of  $\alpha$ over F obviously meets your requirement.